# CSS inline overriding li not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Hi I have just created a simple listing and want to have them display inline.

```
<ul id="inline_display" class="inline_display">
    <li><a href='../'>1</a></li>
    <li><a href='../'>2</a></li>
    <li><a href='../'>3</a></li>
</ul>
```

However I tried both

```
.inline_display > ul > li > a {
  display: inline;
}

.inline_display  ul  li  a {
 display: inline;
}
```

but no luck.

Anyone could help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: a is alreday an inline-element , so what element are you trying to display:inline ?

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for helping me out for the dumb question. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
.inline_display  > li  {
  display: inline;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/K3uXP/)**

In your example, `.inline_display > ul` and `.inline_display ul` won't work because there is no `<ul>` element that's a child of `.inline_display`. `.inline_display` *is* the `<ul>`, so you just need to target the elements below it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a mistake in the selector. `.inline_display` is already exactly your ul so you just need to remove your ul from the selector:

```
.inline_display > li {
  display: inline;
}
```

But IMHO there is a not necessary to apply child selector here ">" you can choose this variant

**CSS**

```
.inline_display li {
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mistake in your CSS. But it doesn't do what you want

```
.inline_display > li > a {
  display: inline;
}

.inline_display li  a {
 display: inline;
}
```

And you can make it shorter, if you want inline LIs. Links are inline normally, if you don't declare them as blocks.

```
.inline_display li {dispaly: inline}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct sytax is

```
ul.inline_display > li {
    display: inline;
}
```

or

```
ul#inline_display >  li {
    display: inline;
}
```

for addressing `li` that is direct child of `ul`

by

```
.inline_display  ul  li  a {
    display: inline;
}
```

you are addressing this structure

```
<div class='inline_display'>
    <ul>
      <li>
         <a> </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, ID it's unique while class can be assigned to multiple DOM elements.

So choose your style, id it's #inline_display while class will be .inline_display

Second: it's not the anchor inline but li.

So:

```
 #inline_display li {
 display: inline;
}
```